# Why did the Apache IoTDB build up process stuck using maven when trying to execute `clean package -pl distribution -am -DskipTests`?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now building the Apache IoTDB environment through maven. When I try to execute `~/iotdb$ mvn clean package -pl distribution -am -DskipTests` command, the download process is stuck and no error popped out. I tried to change the source of maven, but this does not solve the problem. Why did this happened and what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you are connected to an agent during this process. During this process in Apache IoTDB, you cannot connect to an agent, so try to disconnect the agent and try gain.